# How to change unordered list width on click

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm building responsive web site. I have fixed navigation. And my content is changing. I want to change HOME list, for example, width to 180px when I click on it. Can someone help?

This is my code for navigation

HTML

```
<div class="aside">
<ul>
    <li><a class="po" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a class="fo" href="galerija.html">GALERY</a></li>
    <li><a class="ra" href="program.html">PROGRAM</a></li>
    <li><a class="ko" href="ulaznice.html">TICKETS</a></li>
<li><a class="ko" href="kontakt.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.aside ul
{
float:left;
font-size:0.8em;
display:block;
margin-top:10%;
padding: 0px;
max-width:180px:
width:100%;
min-width:140px;

}


.aside li 
{
height:40px;    
list-style:none;
width:100%;
display:block;
text-align:center;
line-height:45px;
padding-top:2px;

}


.aside a
{
background-color:white;
display:block;
height:40px;
width:70%;  
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:1.375em;
font-weight:600;
font-weight:600;
color:#4ea3d9;
-moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
-webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;
-o-transition: all 600ms ease;

}

.aside a:hover
{
width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a class with javascript on click event.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the individual `<li>` element to change its width when clicked?

If you're using Jquery you could do it this way:

```
$('.aside ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).css('width', 180);
});
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sj5gi this is on hover screenshot. Thanks but your method didn't worked..it changes width but after 1 second old width is back.